# Must a player take a jump in checkers?

Tags: checkers

Is a player in checkers required to take a jump if one is available?  What about a double or triple jump if that is available?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

In short -- for tournaments, **yes**.

I never played with forced jumps as a kid, but my father-in-law always plays with forced jumps.  So I did a little digging around, and this is what I found:

The American Checker Federation seems to be the only sanctioned checkers organization I could find.  According to the American Checker Federation, [rule #1.20](http://www.usacheckers.com/rulesofcheckers.php) says

> 1.20  All capturing moves are compulsory, whether offered actively or passively...

Comment: if you have more than one jump available, however, you are not required to take any in preference over another.

Comment: I think you only found one organisation because the rest of the world calls the game something else ;-) Here's a list of others: http://fmjd.org/?p=all

Comment: @tttppp - first football, then Clue, now this??  Seriously, though, thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 12):

There are [many variants of checkers/draughts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draughts), and for all of them (including the Checkers variant played predominantly in the English-speaking world), not only is jumping compulsory, it is also compulsory to keep jumping until all the jumps are completed. Quote from the [American Checkers Federation's official rulebook](http://www.usacheckers.com/downloads/WCDF_Revised_Rules.doc):

> 1.19  **If a jump creates an immediate further capturing opportunity, then the capturing move of the piece (man or king) is continued until
>   all the jumps are completed**. The only exception is that if a man
>   reaches the king-row by means of a capturing move it then becomes a
>   king but may not make any further jumps until their opponent has
>   moved.  At the end of the capturing sequence, all captured pieces are
>   removed from the board.
>
> 1.20  **All capturing moves are compulsory**, whether offered actively or passively. If there are two or more ways to jump, **a player may select
>   any one that they wish, not necessarily that which gains the most
>   pieces**. Once started, a multiple jump must be carried through to
>   completion. A man can only be jumped once during a multiple jumping
>   sequence.

However, the rules for selecting among multiple ways to jump differs from variant to variant. E.g. for [International draughts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_draughts), the sequence with the most jumped pieces has to be selected, and for [Italian draughts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italian_draughts) there are even further tie-breaker rules depending on the number of kings that are being captured.

Answer (score 6):

There are many different [Checkers variants](http://www.checkerschest.com/checkers-games/german-checkers.htm), but I believe most of them use a forced capture rule.

Comment: In fact, *every* checkers variant uses not only the forced capture rule, but also the forced *capture continuation* rule. Where these variants can differ is the *capture precedence* rule. In Checkers as played predominantly in the English-speaking world, a player can play any capture sequence as long as it finishes that sequence. In other variants, capture precedence is given to the longest capture sequence.

Answer (score 4):

I've always had the same rules that [this article](http://boardgames.about.com/cs/checkersdraughts/ht/play_checkers.htm) does (Rule 9), if you can jump, you have to jump at least once, but you don't have to jump any more than that.

Comment: I think you're mis-reading rule 9.  If after the jump you choose there's still another jump available, you _do_ have to take that additional jump - but you don't have to choose the multi-jump move in the first place in preference to some move that only offers a single jump.

Comment: I down-voted this answer as bad, reasons why are explained by the comment above.